# Using webpack's splitChunks option to cache a large file

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting, webpack-4

### tl;dr

Using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)'s [`url-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader), I load some 2300 40px by 30px png icons (small Pokémon sprites) into an array resulting in ~2.2MB of minified JavaScript.  These images and the module that wraps them virtually never change and have no dependencies that do change.  I want to pull them into a separate js file so that, when running `webpack --watch`, every time I change code that depends on that array of images, Webpack doesn't trigger a re-extraction and minification of those images, a process which takes on the order of 20 seconds.

Previously, for things like this I've used a separate entry point and the [`CommonsChunkPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) as documented in the [Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) section of Webpack's documentation.  (I don't know if this was how it was *supposed* to be used, but it worked.)  This is no longer viable since Webpack 4 deprecated the `CommonsChunkPlugin`, but I can't figure out how to use its replacement, `config.optimization.splitChunks`, to achieve the same effect.

---

For some reason, Webpack deprecated its `CommonsChunkPlugin` in favor of the `webpack.optimization.splitChunks` configuration, made using `CommonsChunkPlugin` throw an error when initialized, and then didn't update their [code splitting documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) to reflect this change.  I looked for a couple hours for official documentation on `splitChunks` and how to use it, and the closest I found was this [*"RIP CommonsChunkPlugin"* gist](https://gist.github.com/sokra/1522d586b8e5c0f5072d7565c2bee693) and this [Medium.com article](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366) which only give high-level explanations of the change.

#### `client/pokemon-icons.js`

```js
import Pokedex from 'pokedex'; // has no dependencies

class PokemonIcons {
    constructor() {
        let req = require.context('../resources/icons/regular', false, /\.png$/);
        req.keys().forEach(fn => {
            let species = /([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.png$/.exec(fn)[1];
            this[species] = { regular: req(fn) };
        });

        req = require.context('../resources/icons/shiny', false, /\.png$/);
        req.keys().forEach(fn => {
            let species = /([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.png$/.exec(fn)[1];
            this[species].shiny = req(fn);
        });

        let egg = require('../resources/icons/egg.png');
        this.egg = { regular: egg, shiny: egg };
    }

    getIcon(pokemon) {
        return this[Pokedex.FileNames[pokemon.species]][pokemon.shiny];
    }
}

const icons = new PokemonIcons();
export default icons;
```

There are a couple ways the documentation gives for telling Webpack to extract the code into its own chunk file.

### `require.ensure()`

The "old" method was using `require.ensure()` which takes an array of modules to load, and a callback called after the modules are loaded.

#### `client/soullink/index.js` example

```js
require.ensure(['../pokemon-icons'], () => {
    const config = require('config.json');
    if (config.someFlag) {
        require('./some-js'); // does not rely on `pokemon-icons.js`
    } else {
        require('./some-other-js'); // has dependencies which rely on `pokemon-icons.js`
    }
});
```

This method does, indeed, create a separate chunk file, but that chunk file is still regenerated every time other code is changed.

### `import()`

The "new" method uses `import()` which returns a `Promise`.  Optionally, with babel's `babel-ployfill` and `babel-preset-2017`, we can use `await` syntax.

#### `Promise` syntax

```js
import('../pokemon-images').then(icons => {
    let icon = icons.getIcon(...);
    // ...
});
```

#### `await` syntax

```js
async function getIcon(...args) {
    let icons = await import('../pokemon-images');
    return icons.getIcon(...args);
}
```

I can't get these methods to even produce a separate chunk file, much less cache it.

Neither of these methods are ideal in the first place, as wrapping everything in callbacks, promises, and async functions is a pain, especially since I'm making calls to `getIcon()` in constructors of classes, which can't be marked async (it's simple enough to get around this, but still obnoxious).

### Webpack configs I've tried

I don't know if it matters, but I'm using [`HtmlWebpackPlugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) which generates an HTML file using [`ejs-loader`](https://github.com/okonet/ejs-loader), and then inserts a reference to the entry points listed in the plugin's `chunks` option array.

My config also compiles two entry points and two `HtmlWebpackPlugin`s which require their associated entry.

#### Base webpack.babel.config.js

These are the relevant parts of my webpack config file.

```js
import webpack from 'webpack';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

function genConfig(env, options) {
    return {
        entry: {
            index: './client/slot-display/index',
            soullink: './client/soullink-manager/index', // this is the entry that requires pokemon-icons.js
            vendors: [ 'lodash' ],
        },

        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            chunkFilename: '[name].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.ejs$/,
                    loader: 'ejs-loader',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.png$/,
                    use: [
                        'url-loader'
                    ]
                }
            ],
        },

        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                _: 'lodash',
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: '!!ejs-loader!./client/slot-display/index.ejs',
                filename: 'index.html',
                chunks: ['index'],
                inject: 'body',
                cache: true
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: '!!ejs-loader!./client/soulLink-manager/index.ejs',
                filename: 'soullink/index.html',
                chunks: ['soullink'],
                inject: 'body',
                cache: true
            })
        ]
    };
}

export default genConfig;
```

I've tried adding

```js
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all', // with and without this line
        cacheGroups: { // with and without this object
            default: false, // with and without this line
            pokemonIcons: {
                test: /pokemon-icons\.js$/, // with and without this line
                name: 'pokemon-icons', // also 'pokemonIcons'
                minChunks: Infinity
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```js
entry: {
    pokemonIcons: './client/pokemon-icons', // with and without this separate entry
    // the various soullink entries I've tried:
    soullink: './client/soullink-manager/index',
    soullink: [ './client/pokemon-icons', './client/soullink-manager/index' ], 
    soullink: [ 'babel-polyfill', './client/soullink-manager/index' ],
    soullink: [ 'babel-polyfill', './client/pokemon-icons', './client/soullink-manager/index' ],
}
```

and setting as appropriate:

```js
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        // ...
        chunks: ['pokemonIcons', 'soullink'],
        // ...
    }
]
```

Comment: Quotation: You only need a runtime chunk when using long term caching and on demand loading.
`optimization.runtimeChunk: true`

And I think you don't need to specify vendor as an entry point, as wp4 has it's own algorythm for generating it out of the exisitng entry-points, but this part can be influenced using the `splitchunks` configuration.